# How are conflicts in the end of turn sequence resolved, e.g. with Bond of Pursuit?

Tags: dnd-4e, movement

How are conflicts in the **End of Turn** sequence resolved?

The specific example we had last night was resolving whether the Avenger could **Shift** using the **Bond of Pursuit** [[ddi](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=5332)] end-of-turn effect, when he had an **Immobilised** status imposed by the same target which lasted until the end of the target turn, i.e. resolving the ... *until the end of the targets turn, he was immobilised, so he can't shift* ... versus the ... *but at the end of the targets turn he can shift*

**Bond of Pursuit**

> **Hit** ... If the target doesn’t end its next turn adjacent to you, you can shift a number of squares equal to 1 + your Dexterity modifier as a free action, and you must end that shift closer to the target.

**Immobilized**

> When a creature is immobilized, it can’t move, unless it teleports or is pulled, pushed, or slid.

My understanding is both the start-of-turn and end-of-turn sequences are under the creatures control, so e.g. the order in the start-of-turn of applying ongoing damage and regeneration is up to the creature.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**All effects at the start (or end) of a creature's turn are resolved in the order that creature decides.**

As @Ananisapta found out: from *Rules Compendium*, page 199.

> The creature can choose the order in which things happen at the end of its turn. For instance, if the creature has saving throws to make and is subjected to an affect that damages it at the end of its turn, the creature can choose to take the damage and then make the saving throws or the other way around.

I haven't the reference at hand at the moment, but it seems to me that this rule was present since *Player's Handbook* printing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I see it.

1. The creature's turn ends. The Avenger is no longer immobilized.
2. The avenger checks, now that the turn has ended to see whether the creature is adjacent. If it's not he can shift as he is no longer immobilized.

The phrasing here is "ends it turn" not an on "end of turn" so it happens (IMO) after the turn ends, after the EoT effects clear.

Comment: And then what happens when two or three different effects on "ends it turn" trigger?

Comment: then that would be the choice of the creature. But the point here is that the two effects have different qualifications here. one is End of turn (a specific period), and one is when the turn ends (more nebulous).

Comment: We agree that the wording "ends its turn" is hazy. My interpretation, however, is that it falls in the normal End of Turn sequence of events for the simple reason that I haven't found any other "turn end" definition in the rules.

Comment: One point of interest - Rules Compendium, pg 198 "A creature can't take any actions at the end of its turn.  However, other creatures might have abilities that they can use at the end of that creature's turn."  This suggests that upon the end of the turn of the creature doing the immobilising, it stops doing the action that caused the immobilisation, and THEN the Avenger gets to do his thing.

Comment: Hmmm... the wording of the reference you made is "other creatures might have abilities that they can use at **the end** of that creature's **turn**"... _end of turn_ is used as a noun. This seems to be the final sub-phase of that creature's turn. Wording of Bond of Pursuit uses the expression "ends its turn" (a verb), which made @waxeagle thinking about an instantaneous event that follows the _end of turn_ sub-phase. I am doubtful about the existence of such an event.

Comment: Before getting into the gritty details, it isn't actually specified that the pursuit action itself happens at the end of the target's turn, just that if the target doesn't end its turn adjacent, the Avenger can use a free action to shift.  That is, it doesn't explicitly say it must shift right then, just that it has been enabled to do so.  So there is technically nothing stopping the Avenger just waiting a while, perhaps until the turn of the next creature, and using the free action then, thereby bypassing the entire issue.  It probably isn't in the spirit of the rules, though.

Comment: @Ananisapta I think that's a new question

Comment: @waxeagle - Very likely...but one that probably needs answering before this one can be resolved.